# how to change the report server edition in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

I'm using SSRS to generate a report and I'm having some issues on it. Recently, I have upgraded my SQL Server from SQL Server Express to a full edition. I am assuming that I need to set the edition to SQL Server. Is there any way I can change the edition of my report server? As I am no longer using the SQL Server Express and I need to change it to SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: SQL Server Express **is** SQL Server - there's nothing to "set" or "modify" - just point to the new "full" version of SQL Server (by specifying the server and instance name) and you're done

Comment: And if you don't have another instance to point to.. you need to install the version you need.